# Why is my solution to this Codeschool challenge incorrect?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the CodeSchool question -
Using Map With Arrays

Over at Maple Mountain, the dev team has received some name data from the customer terminal that they want to use to customize greetings for each of their passengers. But the data consists of an array with many subarrays where the first and last names of each passenger are split up.

They want to take the passengers array and convert those subarrays into strings that contain the first and last name for each passenger.

Create a modifiedNames variable to store our new data.

Assign passengers.map() to the modifiedNames variable. This will allow us to pass in a function to be used on every element in the array.

Pass an anonymous function to map().

The anonymous function should take in arrayCell as a parameter and use that to return a string with the first and last name for a passenger. In other words, if you were to pass in a ["Jason", "Millhouse"] array, the function should return a "Jason Millhouse" string.

This is my solution to it -

```js
var passengers = [ ["Thomas", "Meeks"],
                   ["Gregg", "Pollack"],
                   ["Christine", "Wong"],
                   ["Dan", "McGaw"] ];
var modifiedNames= passengers.map(function(arrayCell){
  for( var i=0;i<passengers.length; i++){
   arrayCell= passengers[i][0]+" "+ passengers[i][1];
  }
  return arrayCell;
});
console.log(modifiedNames);
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: The for loop iterates through `passengers`, and always set the values of the last member of the array to the return value. You already have the current "row" in `arrayCell`, use that only to create the return value.

Comment: Sorry Teemu, i am new to this stuff. could you explain it like you are explaining it to a 5 year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function is already looping through your array, so there is no need to loop through it inside. The variable passed through to your function (arrayCell) is essentially passengers[i].

```js
var passengers = [ ["Thomas", "Meeks"],
                   ["Gregg", "Pollack"],
                   ["Christine", "Wong"],
                   ["Dan", "McGaw"] ];
var modifiedNames = passengers.map(function(arrayCell) {
  return arrayCell.join(' '); //arrayCell[0] + ' ' + arrayCell[1];
});
console.log(modifiedNames);
```

The [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function concatenates all elements of an array with the string argument passed in. Using this function instead of the commented code next to it allows this function to return the full name, assuming more than just name and surname were passed in as an array.

Comment: sorry to ask but could you explain this line - return arrayCell.join(' ');. What happened here?

Comment: Edited the answer to hopefully explain a little more.

Comment: doesn't arrayCell[0] mean "Thomas", "Meeks" and  similarly arrayCell[1] mean "Greg","Pollack". So shouldn't arrayCell[0] + ' ' + arrayCell[1] translate into "Thomas", "Meeks" "Gregg", "Pollack".

Comment: passengers[0] = ["Thomas", "Meeks"], but when using passengers.map(function(arrayCell) {..., the first time it is called, arrayCell = passengers[0]. The next it will be equal to passengers[1], etc. So in effect, calling arrayCell[0] is the same as calling passengers[i][0].